# rstudio push 'rpostback-askpass' error

Tags: git, rstudio, ssh-keys

From CLI, I can push/pull to git. However, from Rsudio, I'm only able to pull but not to push. I have opened my firewall for ssh/https ports 
but I'm still getting the following error when trying to push:

```
error: unable to read askpass response from 'rpostback-askpass'
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
```

Rstudio Version 0.99.484.

Comment: What is the point of giving a negative mark for asking a question? Can anyone answer this question?

Answer (score 10):

The problem is in the latest https authentication in RStudio.
(As explained in [this post](https://github.com/OHI-Science/ohicore/issues/104))

The solution is to switch the repository URL from https to ssh by editing the repository's config in your project: .git/config

Then, don't forget to setup public keys on github (Your Profile->Settings->SSH Keys as explained [here](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/))

Comment: Still an issue with RStudio Server `2022.12.0 Build 353`. Solved it by switching to ssh, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is adding the passphrase to the "id_rsa" located in the .ssh directory.  That is what worked on my case. Am using a Linux server.

```
~/.ssh$ ls
**id_rsa  id_rsa.pub  known_hosts
```

Here are the steps:

Step 1: what you would see when you try to ssh from CLI

```
 $ ssh -vT git@github.com
    # ...
    # Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
    # debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
    # Permission denied (publickey).
```

Step 2:
start the ssh-agent in the background

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
# Agent pid 59566
ssh-add
# Enter passphrase for /home/you/.ssh/id_rsa: ***TYPE YOUR PASSPHRASE HERE***
# Identity added: /home/you/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/you/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

Step 3: 
$init 6   <-----reboot your linux server

Now, I can push/pull from Rstudio!

Credit goes to this link: https://help.github.com/articles/error-agent-admitted-failure-to-sign/

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with a new github repository, and setting a public SSH key (as linked by Viliam Simko) did not solve it. Pushing from the command line as suggested by [daattalli](https://github.com/daattali) [here](https://github.com/STAT545-UBC/Discussion/issues/93) did the trick, once and for all.

> The idea is to push using the command line for the first time, when you push from the command line it'll ask you for your credentials, and after that you should be able to push using the RStudio button and you won't have to use the commandline again.
>
> - in RStudio, click on the "Tools" menu and select "Shell"
> - Run the following command: git push -u origin master
> - it might ask you for your git username and password. Supply this information, make sure it is correct
> - hopefully the push is successful, then you can close the window
> - Now make some more edits to some file so that you have new content to push
> - click on the "push" button in RStudio and this time the push should work

Comment: Please post the relevant part of the linked web page here. Links vanish over time, so link-only answers are not welcome here.

Answer (score 0):

As of git 1.9.1, your `$HOME/.gitconfig` file should looks like this:

```
[credential]
        helper = cache --timeout=3600
```

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this from an RStudio server notebook:

```sh
git push
error: cannot run rpostback-askpass: No such file or directory
Username for 'https://stash.mycompany.org':
```

Note the last line is asking for username (e.g. `smithj` or whatever your git/stash username is - it may be an email address). Simply enter the username.

It may then ask for a password, give it that too and you should be ready to go.

Note: for related reasons, I had to reinstall askpass, and did so with:

```sh
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install openssh-client
```

Answer (score -1):

I always get this error when Git does not have my password stored in cache.

To set up git so it stores your password simply enter `credential.helper=cache --timeout=3600` into your git setting like this:

```
git config --global --set credential.helper 'cache --timeout=3600'
```

(Note that this line applies to Linux and slightly differs for other OS.)

Check your Git settings using `git config -l` in your default shell and they should like this (+ additional lines below):

```
user.email=<your.mail>
user.name=<your.username>
credential.helper=cache --timeout=3600
```

Now you have to use the shell the first time you pull/push something from you Github repo. Simply click on `Tools -> Shell` in RStudio. A shell window opens in the directory of your RProject. Type in `git push` and git will ask you for your username and password.

The reason behind that is that Git will ask you for your password in the shell and store it in cache for the time you set in `--timeout=xxxx`.

Now you can use the `push / pull` buttons in RStudio.