# Rstudio git issue "error: unable to read askpass response from 'rpostback-askpass'"

Tags: r, windows, git, rstudio

In Windows 10
after clone repository, it shows:
cloing into 'xxxx'...
/user/bin/env: 'bash': No such file or directory
error: unable to read askpass response from 'rpostback-askpass'"

I have git installed and set up correctly (can run git directly from cmd line)
and access to the repository (have tested from cmd line also)
Is it a bug with Rstudio?

I am struggling to edit .gitconfig file from windows command line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [rstudio push 'rpostback-askpass' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32699891/rstudio-push-rpostback-askpass-error)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%5Brstudio%5D+error%3A+unable+to+read+askpass+response

Comment: my git was installed under Microsoft VS, not sure where can I find $HOME/.gitconfig file?

Comment: [`git config --global …`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34989933/7976758)

Comment: (Note that this line applies to Linux and slightly differs for other OS.)