# Git push error on RStudio - Ubuntu 18.04.4 - Using Conda to run R and RStudio

Tags: r, git, github, rstudio

**Background Info**: I followed instructions on [setting your commit email address](https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/setting-your-commit-email-address) from GitHub to configure the username and email on Git globally. I have chosen to keep my email address private.

The following steps were successfully completed.

- A repository is created on GitHub.
- A new project is created on RStudio using the repository from GitHub.
- An R script, Testing.R is created and committed locally.

**Issue**: Pushing the commit to GitHub from RStudio is throwing the below error.

```
>>> git push origin refs/heads/master
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
```

**What I tried**: I Googled the error and did the below task as instructed at [rstudio-push-rpostback-askpass-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32699891/rstudio-push-rpostback-askpass-error).

- Tried switching the repository URL from `https` to `ssh`, but got the below error.

  `ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
   Host key verification failed.
   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`

My understanding is that if I am able to pull the repo into RStudio, then hopefully there isn't any problem with how I created the credentials in Git, and the connection between RStudio and GitHub is working just fine.

Note: The push to GitHub went successfully through Git CLI. However, it explicitly asked for the credentials.

**Platform Information**:

> R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
>
> Platform: x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu (64-bit)
>
> Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
>
> git version 2.17.1

Please help me resolve the issue.
Thanks.

Comment: What is the remote origin in `git config --list`?(origins should end in `.git`?)

Comment: @NelsonGon Running `git config --list` returned only `user.name` and `user.email`, both of which I manually configured recently.

Comment: Try setting a remote url to the target repo.

Comment: @NelsonGon The remote URL, along with other fields, is already present in `.git/config` under the local repository.

Comment: I think you should try manually setting `remote` with `git remote set-url`. Another option is to clone the repo and just push?(Or just change the Terminal in RStudio to the native Terminal(eg bash/*sh)

Comment: @NelsonGon Okay. I followed the below steps.

(1) Used `git remote set-url` manually [Didn't worked].

(2) Deleted the local repository, including all directories on the disk. Cloned an existing repository from GitHub to RStudio [This worked]. Pushed it right after cloning [Got the same error].

Comment: git remote set-url [current origin] [new-origin] or use git remote add

Comment: @NelsonGon I renamed my old remote. Added the HTTPS URL as origin using `git add remote origin <HTTPS URL>`. Then restarted RStudio, made another commit and tried a push. Unfortunately, it didn't worked.

Comment: Could you link to the repo?

Comment: I didn't get what you mean by _linking_ to the repo. I have cloned the repository, before trying a push, from GitHub, so I guess, yes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would like to thank @NelsonGon for his help.

To update on the issue, I have not found a concrete solution yet, but I will explain the steps I am following as a workaround.

1. To commit through RStudio:

   - Use the commit link at the top right of the window, under the `Git` tab.
2. To push the commit to GitHub:

   - Use the terminal available in RStudio (or, the default system terminal could be used as well).
   - When the RStudio terminal is used, you will find yourself already under your working directory.
   - Run the command `git push`. Provide your GitHub credentials to complete the process.

Answer (score 0):

Following @flamingo_stark's response, I used the terminal on the RStudio and entered `git push`. The response was to request my GitHub username and password. Now, if you had set up a personal access token on your GitHub profile to help you access GitHub via HTTPS, then your personal access token would be the correct password. Avoid putting the password used to create your GitHub account.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think this is better suited as a comment, as it is not a solution to the original problem, just a hint how to handle access tokens.